# How to connect to Microsoft Azure virtual machine on Windows Subsystem for Linux through SSH?

Tags: azure, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I created a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine with Windows 10 as the image. I allowed it to have an SSH connection. The connection on the Microsoft Azure portal says "Network connectivity allowed". However, when I try to connect it on the Windows Subsystem for Linux using the command: `ssh -i <private key path> <vm-name>@<host ip address>` it says `ssh: connect to host <host ip address> port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable`. Why is this happening?

I am also wondering about the instructions on the Microsoft Azure instructions on creating a private key and then having a private key path. How am I suppose to create a private key and have a path for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [microsoft/WSL/issue 2278](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2278), which lists a couple of issues:

- firewall

  > - the domain had been moved to cloud front and I needed to use the direct IP address instead of the domain name.
  > - I received a "Resource temporarily unavailable" error because my subnet did not have a route to an Internet Gateway
  > - I just had this problem because I installed Nginx in the server and it blocks SSH by default. You have to `sudo ufw allow ssh`.

Note: as explained in "[Connect to an Azure Linux vm with ssh and Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://matthewdavis111.com/azure/connect-azure-linux-ssh/)" by **[matthewdavis111](https://matthewdavis111.com/about/)**, you connect from WSL to Azure.

Meaning you would enter your public key in the SSH field of your Azure remote server:

[image: https://matthewdavis111.com/images/wsl-ssh-azure/basic-settings.png]

On your PC, you can generate a public/private key with:

```
ssh-keygen -P "" -t rsa -f azure
```

That will create in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` an `azure` and `azure.pub` files.
Copy the content of the second one (public key) to Azure settings.

Depending on your version of Windows 10, you might need to install [Git for Widows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), which includes `ssh-keygen.exe`.

```
C:\path\to\Git\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe
```

In your case though, doing so in  a WSL bash session is better, especially if the rest is done from that same session.
The files will be in `~/.ssh` (`$HOME/.ssh`)

---

For a Windows 10 VM, see "[Creating A Win 10 Virtual Machine – Azure Portal](http://www.ayushrathi.com/creating-a-win-10-virtual-machine-azure-portal/)" by **[Ayush Rathi](https://twitter.com/ayushrathi15)**.
No need for SSH then.

> ### Connecting to the Virtual Machine and Log On:
>
> 1. On the Hub menu, click Virtual Machines.
> 2. Select the virtual machine from the list.
>
> [image: 13 Click on Connect]
>
> 3. On the Virtual Machine Blade, Click on Connect. This creates and downloads a Remote Desktop Protocol file (.rdp file) to connect to your machine. Open this file to connect to your VM.
> 4. You will get a warning that the .rdp is from an unknown publisher.This is a normal warning. In the Remote Desktop window, click Connect to continue.
>
> [image: 14 RDP Click Connect]
>
> 5. In the Windows Security window, type the username and password that you entered while creating the VM. The username is entered as vmname\username, then click OK.
>
> [image: 15 Enter Username & Password]
>
> 6. You will get a warning that the identity of the remote computer cannot be verified. This is a normal warning. Click Yes to verify the identity of the virtual machine and finish logging on.
>
> [image: 16 Certificate]
>
> Your machine is ready and you can use it just as you would use any other machine or server.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried the solutions given there, however, the error still shows up. I tried creating a new Outbound rule on Windows Firewall and did the above ```sudo``` command. The ```sudo``` command gives an error: ```[sudo] password for user:
WARN: initcaps
[Errno 2] iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.```.

Comment: @user12055579 How did you create your SSH public/private key? And did you register your public key on Azure side?

Comment: I did not create an SSH public or private key. When setting up the VM, it didn't give me that option. How would I be able to set up the key within the Azure portal?

Comment: @user12055579 Are you trying to connect from Azure to your PC (WSL session)?

Comment: @user12055579 Generally, you do so from PC to Azure: https://matthewdavis111.com/azure/connect-azure-linux-ssh/

Comment: Yeah, for some reason I did not have that option.

Comment: @user12055579 Do you mean you have to connect from Azure to your PC? Why?

Comment: No, I mean to connect from my PC to Azure.

Comment: @user12055579 So my answer and the article https://matthewdavis111.com/azure/connect-azure-linux-ssh/ are still relevant in your case.

Comment: Yes, but do you know how I am able to obtain a private/public key?

Comment: @user12055579 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Would I run that on the command line or the bash terminal for WSL?

Comment: If it does not work in a simple CMD, the WSL bash might be more appropriate.

Comment: I am getting: ```Too many arguments.
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa] ... ``` on both the command line and WSL bash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210116/discussion-between-vonc-and-user12055579).